# Python Xlrd Result format

Tags: python, xlrd

i want to know, the result format of xlrd.

See the code

```
>>> sh.cell_value(rowx=2, colx=1)
u'Adam Gilchrist xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Now when i try running a res.search

```
>>> temp1=sh.cell_value(rowx=2, colx=1)
>>> x=re.search("Adam",'temp1')
>>> x.group()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#58>", line 1, in <module>
    x.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I get nothing.

1. First i want to know , what is the 'u' with result.
2. What are the result formats returned by `sh.cell_value`. Is it integer, string etc.
3. Can we run regular expressions on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question first

1. First i want to know , what is the 'u' with result?  u is the qualifier for [unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) string. So `u'Adam Gilchrist xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'` means the test in unicode.
2. What are the result formats returned by sh.cell_value . Is it integer , string etc.? Its unicode string
3. Can we run regular expressions on them ? Yes you can and this is how you do

> ```
> temp1=u'Adam Gilchrist xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> x=re.search(u'Adam',temp1)    
> x.group()    
> u'Adam'
> ```

Its only that you have to specify the pattern in unicode also.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a Unicode string
2. Cell_value returns the value of the cell. The type depends on the type of the cell.
3. Yes. You can use regular expressions on Unicode strings, but your code isn't right.

Your code passes "temp1" to re.search as a string. It does not pass the variable temp1.  You want:

```
>>> x=re.search(u"Adam",temp1)
```

Comment: Your right . I corrected the mistake already.And i had to convert the temp1 into str(temp) , for re.search to successfully search . Thanks dude .

Comment: You're welcome. To accept the answer, there should be a check mark.  Until then, so will list it as having no accepted answer.

Comment: -1 @CarlF.: Sorry, your implementation "works" only when the pattern contains only ASCII. You have unicode data, use a unicode pattern.

Comment: @arindamroychowdhury: You don't need to use `str()` in the ASCII-only example that you gave, and you should NOT use it in general. You have unicode data, so work in unicode.

Comment: @John Machin: I disagree about it not working with Unicode.  Just tried it in Python 2.6 and it works fine.  Nevertheless, I edited to support unicode.

Comment: The answer definately works , BUT , i am using a variable for pattern . I mean , look at this code ->
 "temp1=sh.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=j)"
x=re.search(patn,temp1)

Now, in above example , I can add the search(u'Some string')
But i have a variable in which ,pattern is stored.
How do i add 'u' with variable ?
If i do x=re.search(u'patn',temp1), It becomes a String.
Any ideas?